# Sampling a single element from a ranges-v3 view and storing the value

Tags: c++, range-v3

I'm trying to create a one-liner using the ranges-v3 library to sample a single element from a vector and directly hold the result inside a `value_type` object. I can do this in 2 steps as shown below, but I wonder if it's possible to do this in a single line.

Trying `int value = *ranges::begin(my_vec | ranges::views::sample(1));` doesn't seem to work.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <range/v3/range/conversion.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/sample.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/iota.hpp>
#include <range/v3/range/operations.hpp>
#include <range/v3/range/access.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> my_vec = ranges::view::iota(-10, 11) | ranges::to_vector;
    auto sampled = my_vec | ranges::views::sample(1);
    int value = *ranges::begin(sampled);

    std::cout << value << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```